# Raml validator throws an error in javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema

Tags: maven-2, yaml, osgi-bundle, raml, raml-java-parser

When trying to validate [espn.raml](http://api.apihub.com/onpositive/api/espn-raml-api/espn.raml) I got the below error. Same code is working fine for [gmail.raml](http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/onpositive/api/gmail-raml-api/gmail.raml). Why is this happening?
For your reference I have included the results I found what are the jars that SchemaFactory includes.

> $ find *.jar | xargs grep SchemaFactory.class Binary file
>
> axiom_1.2.11.wso2v6.jar matches Binary file
>
> org.apache.openjpa_2.2.0.wso2v1.jar matches Binary file
>
> solr_5.2.1.wso2v1.jar matches

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;)Ljavax/xml/validation/Schema;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/raml/parser/rule/SchemaRule, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory, have different Class objects for the type m/Source;)Ljavax/xml/validation/Schema; used in the signature
    at org.raml.parser.rule.SchemaRule.doValidateValue(SchemaRule.java:118)
    at org.raml.parser.rule.SchemaRule.doValidateValue(SchemaRule.java:48)
    at org.raml.parser.rule.DefaultTupleRule.validateValue(DefaultTupleRule.java:108)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.YamlDocumentValidator.onScalar(YamlDocumentValidator.java:115)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitScalar(NodeVisitor.java:256)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visit(NodeVisitor.java:222)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitResolvedNode(NodeVisitor.java:180)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.doVisitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:151)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:86)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visit(NodeVisitor.java:218)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitResolvedNode(NodeVisitor.java:180)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.doVisitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:151)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:86)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visit(NodeVisitor.java:218)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitResolvedNode(NodeVisitor.java:180)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.doVisitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:151)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:86)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visit(NodeVisitor.java:218)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitResolvedNode(NodeVisitor.java:180)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.doVisitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:151)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:86)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visit(NodeVisitor.java:218)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitResolvedNode(NodeVisitor.java:180)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.doVisitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:151)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:86)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visit(NodeVisitor.java:218)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitResolvedNode(NodeVisitor.java:180)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.doVisitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:151)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:86)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visit(NodeVisitor.java:218)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitResolvedNode(NodeVisitor.java:180)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.doVisitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:151)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:86)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visit(NodeVisitor.java:218)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitResolvedNode(NodeVisitor.java:180)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.doVisitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:151)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:86)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visit(NodeVisitor.java:218)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitResolvedNode(NodeVisitor.java:180)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.doVisitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:151)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitDocument(NodeVisitor.java:209)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.YamlValidationService.validate(YamlValidationService.java:65)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.YamlValidationService.validate(YamlValidationService.java:95)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.YamlValidationService.validate(YamlValidationService.java:82)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.YamlValidationService.validate(YamlValidationService.java:72)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor.isValidateRAML(RAMLProcessor.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor.processRAML(RAMLProcessor.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.RAMLMediaTypeHandler.put(RAMLMediaTypeHandler.java:157)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
    ... 78 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding xml-apis from raml-parser did the job.

```
<exclusion>
 <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
 <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

Now its validating without a issue.

Comment: Cool but that's not a nice incentive for people to answer you. My answer was pointing to that but with the information you provided, it was impossible to see that `xml-apis` was on the classpath. You could have commented on my answer for me to review it with this info then accepted it.

Comment: Yes sir I know that your answer showed me the place to look at. thank you very much and keep up the good work.

Answer (score 5):

This is weird. I have no problem running the following:

```
RamlValidationService
  .createDefault()
  .validate("http://api.apihub.com/onpositive/api/espn-raml-api/espn.raml");
```

It throws no exception and returns an empty `List<ValidationResult>`, as this RAML file is valid.

My environment:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

In my case, `javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory` is provided by the JDK itself. You should strive for the same, ie make sure that no other library can contribute this class to your code, either by using alternate JARs that don't contain this class (these seem to be WSO2 specific versions, other versions may be different?) or by using classloader filtering, if the execution environment allows it.

**EDIT** As added in the comments, the fix was to exclude `xml-apis:xml-apis` from RAML Parser. This exclusion makes sense since recent JDKs provided what's needed by RAML Parser.