# Sample RAMLs available online

Tags: yaml, raml, raml-java-parser

I would like to know if there are any publicly available APIs documented with RAML.

I have these 2 which are working fine:

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raml-org/raml-tutorial-200/step8/jukebox-api.raml
>
> http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/onpositive/api/gmail-raml-api/gmail.raml

These 3 are not working for some reason:

> http://api.apihub.com/onpositive/api/espn-raml-api/espn.raml >>
>   [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570593/raml-validator-throws-an-error-in-javax-xml-validation-schemafactory-newschema)
>
> http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/github/api/github-api-v3/github-api-v3.raml
>
> http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/instagram/api/instagram-api/instagram-api.raml

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you mean that you want some public examples of RAML files? And what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: In the java parser validation those 3 are failing.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. If you're concerned with an issue in the parser, ask a new question with the violations received so we can discuss what's happening.

Comment: Im just creating rest service metadata xml by reading raml. While doing that I uncounted some problems. Please find below question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570593/raml-validator-throws-an-error-in-javax-xml-validation-schemafactory-newschema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some valid RAML specs I know of:

- https://github.com/openanalytics/RPooli/blob/master/webapp/src/main/webapp/raml/api_v1.raml
- https://api.unbounce.com/raml/v0.4/api.raml

Comment: Hi David, 
2nd one looks fine and validation passes successfully. but the 2nd one gives me "mapping values are not allowed here" error. why is that??
Thanks,

Comment: Both are used in production and consumed by tools like RAML Tester and API Console so this is strange. Anyway, I'm unclear about what you report: is it the first one of the second one that gives this error?

Comment: sorry for the typo, My above comment should corrected like this >>>>

2nd one looks fine and validation passes successfully. but the 1st one(api_v1.raml) gives me "mapping values are not allowed here" error. why is that?? Thanks,

Comment: OK, and where is "here" as reported in the exception? This is maybe due to the templated `baseUri`.

Comment: looks like I'm getting that validation error for all the ramls that are hosted in github, Here is a another one with the same error >> http://postimg.org/image/4wresdq6b/

Comment: Of course, you're trying to validate the HTML page from Github. You need to load the raw content, like from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openanalytics/RPooli/master/webapp/src/main/webapp/raml/api_v1.raml

Comment: that was the issue! thanks! I have one other question in api_v1.raml the baseURI is "${baseUri}/api/{version}" I cant find the value for the {baseUri}..

Comment: It's dynamically injected when the RAML spec is served over HTTP: https://github.com/openanalytics/RPooli/blob/master/webapp/src/main/java/eu/openanalytics/rpooli/web/BaseUriInjectionFilter.java#L44

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90554/discussion-between-thusharak-and-david-dossot).

Answer (score 1):

There are also some valid RAMLs here https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/tree/master/dist/examples

Comment: Only https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mulesoft/api-console/master/dist/examples/stripe.raml is working for me. Are you sure these should work out of the box?

Comment: Yep, you need to use the raw version - otherwise it's not working.